# What's the best practice to validate each field in separate test for pytest

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have service which respond with some flat json. Like `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`. I want to do the following scenario:

1. create list of input params for requests
2. do request to server with params
3. validate each field from responses as a separate test

For now I have the following solution:

```
import pytest


def Server(*args):
    def do_request():
        # apply some config and do request
        return {'f1': args[0],
                'f2': args[1]}

    return do_request()


@pytest.fixture(scope="class")
def case(request):
    return Server(*request.param), request.param


@pytest.mark.parametrize('case', [(1, 2), (3, 4)], indirect=True)
class TestIndividualField:
    def test_f1(self, case):
        assert case[0]['f1'] == case[1][0]

    def test_f2(self, case):
        assert case[0]['f2'] == case[1][1]
```

In this case I do only one request for class which is the most important because response takes some time.

Do you have an ideas how I can improve this code? I think I am missing something about fixtures possibility or patterns which I could use

Comment: Why do you want to validate each field in a different test function?

Comment: I want to collect assertion statistics for each field from the response.